# Using NSOperationQueue for delayed free of malloc'd void* after returning it

Tags: objective-c, c, malloc, objective-c-blocks, nsinvocation

I'm using `NSInvocation` to get some method returns, and unfortunately I seem to have a leak, but can't figure out how to free the `void*` I'm allocating, after I've returned it from `NSInvocation`.

In the following implementation I tried to free it with a block that gets performed on the next run loop, but I get a crash due to `returnBuffer` not being allocated.

Why can't I free `returnBuffer` in the block, and if it hasn't been allocated why is it getting through `returnBuffer!=NULL`?

This is a special method that has to do with `IMP` swizzling so I DON'T know the method return type. Putting it in `NSData` or something will not work.

```
NSUInteger length = [[invocation methodSignature] methodReturnLength];
if(length!=0){
    void* returnBuffer = (void *)malloc(length);
    [invocation getReturnValue:&returnBuffer];
    if(returnBuffer!=NULL){
        void(^delayedFree)(void) = ^{ free(returnBuffer); };
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:delayedFree];
    }
    return returnBuffer;
}
return nil;
```

***ANSWER***
Got it to work the following way thanks to Josh's `-[NSMutableData mutableBytes]` trick

```
 NSUInteger length = [[invocation methodSignature] methodReturnLength];
if(length!=0){
    NSMutableData * dat = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:length];
    void* returnBuffer =  [dat mutableBytes];
    [invocation getReturnValue:&returnBuffer];
    void(^delayedFree)(void) = ^{ [dat release]; };
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:delayedFree];
    return returnBuffer;
}
return nil;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a `void *` from `NSMutableData`, just like you can from `malloc()`, and essentially turn it into an instance variable, so that the lifetime of the allocation is tied to the lifetime of the instance. I got this trick from [Mike Ash](https://github.com/mikeash/MABlockClosure/blob/master/MABlockClosure.m). I've been doing some `NSInvocation` monkeying myself lately; this is in a category on `NSInvocation` (you should use your own prefix for the method, of course):

```
static char allocations_key;
- (void *) Wool_allocate: (size_t)size {
    NSMutableArray * allocations = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, 
                                                            &allocations_key);
    if( !allocations ){
        allocations = [NSMutableArray array];
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &allocations_key, 
                                 allocations, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }

    NSMutableData * dat = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: size];
    [allocations addObject:dat];

    return [dat mutableBytes];
}
```

I'm not sure where the code you've posted is located; if you're in your own custom class, you don't need to deal with the associated objects bits -- just make `allocations` an ivar.

Tying this into your code:

```
NSUInteger length = [[invocation methodSignature] methodReturnLength];
if(length!=0){
    void* returnBuffer = [self Wool_allocate:length];
    [invocation getReturnValue:&returnBuffer];
    return returnBuffer;
}
return nil;
```

If you use the associated object route, the `allocations` array will be deallocated when this instance is. Otherwise, just put `[allocations release]` into your `dealloc`.

Also, to answer your question as posed, rather than just solving the problem: `free()` won't operate on any pointer that you didn't get from `malloc()`. When the pointer gets used in the Block, I'm pretty sure it gets copied, so you end up with *another* pointer -- still pointing to the same memory, but one that `free()` doesn't think it owns. Thus, you get the error about not having allocated it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not quite following your implementation but the NSMutableData mutableBytes trick seems to be exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Glad it's helpful! I can try to clarify anything you want.

Comment: Sorry I should have made that more clear. I'm not "following" your implementation as in I'm not implementing it the same way. You were very clear in your answer about your implementation.

Comment: Okay, great, glad you've got it working. Also, I just realized (I think) why you were actually getting the crash; I added a paragraph at the end to explain.

Comment: Oh nice, I was still wondering why that didn't work. I figured it had to do with something related to C pointers in blocks.

Comment: There's always weirdness at the ObjC/C border, and it's only been getting weirder with Blocks and ARC. Gotta keep yr eye out! ;)